How to access props.location from Link state with Typescript
I need to pass data between pages that do not relate.
I'm new to Typescript, doing this without it would be simple but what's the best way to do it with TS? Also, how do I type notation it?
Here's the component where Link is used:
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { useState } from "react"


export const pageOne = () => {

const [example, setExample] = useState(true)

return (
  <Link to="/pageTwo" state={example}>
     <button> Go to pageTwo </button>
  </Link>
)
}

And the component where I need to access state:

type props = {
// How to type notation the state coming from Link as props?
}

export const pageTwo = (props: props) = {

const {state} = props.location // this doesn't work 

return (
  <>
    {state && <div>Test</div>}
  </>
)
}

Router component
import { pageOne } from ...
import { pageTwo } from ...

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.app}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<pageOne/>} />
          <Route path="/pageTwo" element={<pageTwo/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

Also getting: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'props' in the same component but inside the Router.

Firstly, try to pass an object instead of a primitive. I think you should do:
state={{example}}

Secondly, the new way to access state in the target component is using the hook useLocation.
<Link to="new-path" state={{ some: "value" }} />

let { state } = useLocation();

Docs
If you want type checking, you should pass the expected type inside the component.
export const pageTwo = (props: props) = {

const {state} = useLocation<{ example : boolean}>(); //state.example will be a boolean now

return (
  <>
    {state.example && <div>Test</div>}
  </>
)
}

Here is the type declaration of useLocation, which shows that the type we pass as the generic parameter will be the return type of the state key.
declare function useLocation(): Location;

interface Location<State = any> extends Path {
  state: State;
  key: string;
}


This should do but unfortunately when I get useLocation() on the component I want to use the state is null for some reason

Have edited the answer. You had to pass an object.
